# new-expression evaluation order in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

By [cppreference/eval_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) rule 12 the call to the allocation function (`operator new`) is sequenced before (since C++17) the evaluation of the constructor arguments in a new-expression. Thus, I thought the following

```
Bar b;
Foo* f = new Foo(b.fun());
```

at runtime results in calling `new` first then `fun()` on `b` and lastly the constructor of `Foo`. Both Clang and ICC produce this order. However GCC calls `fun()` first, then the `operator new` and then the constructor.

Who is right? What am I missing?

Comment: This is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86347

Comment: Given that the new-expression can construct the `Foo` object in-place in the memory allocated by `new`, this looks suboptimal...  How did you test it, overload new and print?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, yeah meanwhile I've found also. This is a more than 2 years old bug report, so its resolution is still on the way... Even though it might be not so important but more than 2 years, come on guys! Anyways, thanks!

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, yup, overload new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the standard (version [N4835.pdf](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4835.pdf)):

> **7.6.2.7 New [expr.new]**
> 23 The invocation of the allocation function is sequenced before the evaluations of expressions in the new-initializer. Initialization of the allocated object is sequenced before the value computation of the new-expression.

In your case `b.fun()` is the only expression in the new-initializer.

It looks like Clang, ICC and MSVC do it right and GCC does it wrong. It could be worth asking the GCC guys and maybe filing a bug report (or maybe there already exists one?).

Comment: It's not essential, but adding a link to the draft that you're referring to would be nice.